# Is "standard" an archaic synonym for an athletic team or club?

Tags: british-english, phrase-meaning, colloquialisms, archaicisms

This was passed along to me (native US speaker) by a non-native speaker.

A school in the UK asks for the following details...

> **Games**
>
> **Teams and Standards**
>
> **Extra-curricular Activities**

...in their application form for prospective students.

Our best guess was that "standard" was a synonym for "team" in British English, but I decided to research it.

Couldn't find a definition for "standard" in Wiktionary, Cambridge or MacMillan dictionaries that fit this context.

Web search with exact-match terms "teams and standards" didn't turn up anything conclusive.

Perhaps the obvious conclusion is they meant "ability", in which case they'd be asking for "teams and playing standards". In that case, the phrasing is unfamiliar to us.

The school is in Oxfordshire, on the off-chance regional dialects need to be considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Standard* is not a synonym for *team.* If the form is asking what games the student has taken part in at their previous school, I would assume that it means "what sports teams have they been a member of, and to what standard (i.e. level) do they play?"